# Sonar scanner failing with sonar.binaries and sonar.libraries are not supported

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

My Sonarqube scanner is throwing below error, I am using Sonarqube-5.6.6, Sonar Plugin 2.3 and Jenkins version is 1.625 & Java 8. Kindly help me understand what the error is pointing to and how to fix the issue.

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project common-crawler: sonar.binaries and sonar.libraries are not supported since version 4.0 of sonar-java-plugin, please use sonar.java.binaries and sonar.java.libraries instead

Comment: This post has a similar error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44532429/2745495.

Comment: Hello Gino, I took a look, is it on sonar.properties we have to add those properties ?

Comment: Why not upgrade to the latest LTS version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below properties:

`sonar.java.binaries=`

`sonar.java.libraries=`

`sonar.sources=`

Please add appropriate paths to above properties.